# Flink KeyedProcessFunction integrating anonymous methods

Tags: apache-flink

I am attempting to write a keyedProcessFunction, the code looks like this below:

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> busyMachinesPerWindow = busyMachines
        // group by timestamp (window end)
        .keyBy(event -> event.getField(1))
        .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple1<Long>, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>, Tuple2<Long, Integer>>() {

            private ValueState<Integer> state;

            @Override
            public void open(Configuration config) throws IOException {
                // initialize the state descriptors here
                state = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("machine-counts", Integer.class));
                if (state.value() == null) {
                    state.update(0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void processElement(Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> inWindow, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                if (state.value() != null) {
                    state.update(state.value() + 1);
                } else {
                    state.update(1);
                }
                ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(inWindow.f1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                int counter = state.value();
                state.clear();
                // we can now output the window and the machine count
                out.collect(new Tuple2<>(((Tuple1<Long>) ctx.getCurrentKey()).f0, counter));
            }
        });
```

However this pops up an error saying cannot derive anonymous method. I don't see what the problem is with this code. Is there some type ambiguity that I am not doing right?

Comment: Please share the exact wording of the error message. Also, is this failing at compile time, or while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with this code is that you are calling `state.value()` and `state.update(0)` in the `open` method. This is not allowed. These methods can only be used in `processElement` and in `onTimer`, because only then is there a specific event being processed whose key can be used to access/update the appropriate entry in the state backend.

An instance of a `KeyedProcessFunction` is multiplexed across all of the keys assigned to a given task slot. The `open` method is called just once, at a time when there is no specific key in the runtime context, so the state cannot be accessed or updated at this time.